# objects don't snap in browser window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management, thumbnails

I've recently upgraded from XP Pro to Windows7 Pro - In XP Pro (and previous OS versions) you could move Thumbnails around in a window and they would snap/shuffle up/re-order themselves and be viewable as a slide show - it was unbelievably useful - I used it EVERY day, Windows 7 doesn't do this? Is there some setting I can change or is it just not there anymore?
I use it for organising photo libraries for archiving - I haven't found any other way of doing this that suits my work. Does anyone know a way to get this feature back?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the "view" option to view as thumbnail, and it should be usable again.

Comment: thanks - but there is no thumbnail option in Windows 7 and I have tried every option to be able to make this work.

Comment: in answer to my own question - having spoken directly to Microsoft - both of these features have been removed!

Comment: wait, so is this in windows explorer or what?